# creation of a file along with the current time.....please help me out...!

Tags: java, file, time

myfolder is my directory name in E drive

```
 Date date1 = new Date();
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
 String fileName = dateFormat.format(date1);
 File file = new File("E://"+"myfolder/"+fileName+".txt")`
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: On Windows you can't use colons in file names.

Comment: You really need to give us more detail than that.  What sort of error messages are you getting?  What outputs are you getting when you try to debug the app?  That sort of thing.

Comment: You should add a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in comments, you can't use colons.

The other problem is that you expect that `new File` will create the file in your directory. It won't, it's just an abstract representation of it.

You can call [`createNewFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) to create it on your disk.

I.e :

```
Date date1 = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss");
String fileName = dateFormat.format(date1);
File file = new File("C://Temp//"+fileName+".txt"); //created in temp to see
if(file.createNewFile()){
    System.out.println("created");
} else {
    System.out.println("not created");
}
```

Comment: even above code does not create any file in temp folder... can you please tell me alternative method

Comment: @user3452133 It does for me. Does it print created?

Comment: :import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class  FileCreate
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  Date date1 = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH-mm-ss");
String fileName = dateFormat.format(date1);
File file = new File("C://Temp//"+fileName+".txt"); //created in temp to see
if(file.createNewFile())
 {
    System.out.println("created");
}
else 
 {
    System.out.println("not created");
  }

 }

}// can we create like this??